# JSON-LD in Jena RIOT?

Tags: rdf, jena, json-ld

I got Jena 2.12.1 (2014-10-02) from the [Apache Jena Releases](https://jena.apache.org/download/index.cgi) page.
It's supposed to have JSON-LD support, according to [Reading and Writing RDF in Apache Jena](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/). 
But when I try to use `riot` with an output format of JSON-LD, I get an error (and the same happens for variants in capitalization, hyphenation, etc.):

```
riot --out=JSON-LD NIF-example2.ttl
```

```
   Turtle
   N-Quads
   N-Triples
   TriG
   RDF_THRIFT
Not recognized as an streaming RDF language : 'JSON-LD'
```

How can I write in JSON-LD?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has correctly identified JSON-LD.  JSON-LD is not a streaming output language (the writer needs all the data available before calling the jsonld-java code) and `riot` is a streaming parser (it can cope with files of any size) and needs to write in a streaming fashion.

The tool to read in the data into memory and write it out is `rdfcat`.

```
rdfcat -out JSONLD NIF-example2.ttl
```

Comment: Just to note that @AndyS has changed the implementation slightly so that `riot --output JSON-LD` now works. `--output` means "output, streaming if possible".

Answer (score 0):

More recent RIOT versions (since late 2015) support JSONLD.
However, I don't see a way to give it a context

- there's no option for that
- I tried providing a context inside the jsonld file like this (see https://gist.github.com/VladimirAlexiev/6ab60b6a0e1ab32a2f3980c57b005d8f):

  {"@context":"gvp-context.jsonld", "@graph":[...]}

But it's ignored and it makes its own context.